# SSH and telnet in Hyper V

Tags: firewall, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, virtual-network

I have installed Windows server 2012 and setup a VM using Hyper-V. I have setup networking using a virtual switch on one of the NIC with address 10.0.0.20. I have assigned a static ip to Ubuntu VM 10.0.0.20 same as the IP of the Virtual switch.

I can ping any address on the network and even public address including domains e.g. Google. I have setup static nat e.g. public ip 192.0.2.7 to 10.0.0.20.

For example, I can ssh into 192.0.2.7 but when I am inside the windows server and I can't ssh or telnet to 10.0.0.20.

I have checked the firewall on Windows machine, it is off and I have checked the firewall on Ubuntu machine, it is off.

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say `What?`

Answer (score 11):

> i have setup networking using virtual switch on one of the NIC 10.0.0.20. i a have assigned a static ip to Ubuntu 10.0.0.20 VM same as the IP of the Virtual switch.

So… you've assigned the same IP to two different devices on the network and you still expected it to work?

That dog won't hunt, son.

Comment: +1 Only because I laughed at that last line.